# Is it possible to supply empty password in CreateProcessWithLogonW?

Tags: winapi

Been trying to figure this out while also searching the web.

Below is a working code:

```
bool isCreated = false;
if (requireAdmin)
{
    isCreated = CreateProcessWithLogonW(userName.c_str(), domainName.c_str(), userPass.c_str(), LOGON_WITH_PROFILE, NULL, command, 0, NULL, NULL, &startUpInfo, &procInfo);
}
else
{
    isCreated = CreateProcessW(NULL, command, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &startUpInfo, &procInfo);
}
```

**EXCEPT** when supplied with an Administrator that has no password (which is fine with Windows)

So is it possible? I'd like to align with Windows behavior as much as possible unless an official document says otherwise.

Reference with the sort of similar problem (also unanswered):
https://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?482203-LogonUser-fails-with-empty-password-Why

**UPDATE**

Additional information:

The function above is called by an application that also requires Admin privileges.

Application - Run As Admin (no password)

Function - using Admin (no password)

Comment: Did you try simply passing an empty string in the password parameter? Or a null pointer? Those are your own options when you don't have any other password value to pass in.

Comment: It is an empty string, it was just two double quotation marks

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc:[CreateProcessWithLogonW function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createprocesswithlogonw)

> lpPassword:The clear-text password for the lpUsername account.

If the password for the username account is an empty string? If so, as far as I'm concerned, you could use empty string in `CreateProcessWithLogonW`.

Comment: I already saw that document and it only mentioned clear-text password not empty/blank. I initially thought I could use empty string but it doesn't work.

Comment: I made an update to the question, adding the reference link to a similar problem

Comment: @LindaSingh did you try a null pointer? An empty string and a null string are not the same thing.

Comment: Also tried that, still doesn't work. I added additional information above

Answer (score 0):

The thread you posted CreateProcessAsUser/CreateProcessWithLogonW fails with empty password because of local policy. Like this:
[image: P1:restriction logon]

If you want to use CreateProcessAsUser/CreateProcessWithLogonW with empty password, you must disable the limit.
[image: P2:local policy]

Then I used the CreateProcessWithLogonW function to open the specified loggg.exe by setting an empty password. The program works well.
[image: P3: logon]

Comment: Limit policy in gpedit.msc is Disabled by default. I updated the question with additional information

Comment: @LindaSingh I ran my program successfully under any condition. What's the error code of *CreateProcessWithLogonW*? Do your account have the [**Log On Locally permission on the local computer**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createprocesswithlogonw#parameters)?

Comment: Here's the error: `The stub received bad data.`

Comment: Hello @LindaSingh, Try to [Specify domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18807924/stub-received-bad-data).

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67066150/run-a-process-as-administrator-from-non-admin-user-local-admin-credentials. For *The directory name is invalid*, [Specify WorkingDirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990562/win32exception-the-directory-name-is-invalid).

Comment: hello @YangXiaoPo-MSFT, I did add a domain though the PC is not part of a domain. So I used its hostname

Comment: @LindaSingh So did you successfully call CreateProcessWithProcessW? Do you have any other questions?

Comment: hello @Torrecto-MSFT, it was not successful. Even specifying the domain which is the hostname, it will still return the error `The stub received bad data.`

Comment: @LindaSingh I can only give you some advice. First of all, avoid using the `c_str( )` function in the account and password to convert the string type, directly use the string `L "Administrator"`. If no more errors are returned, you can determine that an error occurred in the data during string conversion. Secondly, set the domain to `NULL`. If the error is not returned, you can confirm that it is a domain authority issue.  Of course, it may also be related to native permissions, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27272919/createprocesswithlogonw-error-1783-the-stub-received-bad-data